# PDO MySQL class

Tags: php, object-oriented, pdo

I'm new to using PDO and am trying to create a secure class to handle MySQL statements. Here is what I have so far:

```
class SQL {
private static $dbh = null;

private function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $data, $table) {
    $this->host = (!empty($host)) ? $host: 'localhost';
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->table = $table;
    static::connect();
}
private function __destruct() {
    static::close();
}
public static function connect() {
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this->table . ';host=' . $this->host;
    static::$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass);
    static::$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
public static function close() {
    static::$dbh = null;
}
public static function query($query) {
    $sth = static::$dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute();
}
}
```

Is what I've done correct so far and conform to best practices?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I've not tackled SQL or PDO as of yet, so this answer will focus mainly on the code itself.

You should not set `$this->data` in the `__construct()` method unless you are planning on using it. I would set it in whatever method you use to add that data. I am assuming this class is incomplete because I did not find it being used anywhere (maybe I missed it?). Doing this you won't have to hunt for that variable later when trying to debug it.

If the only time you are going to use your `connect()` and `close()` methods are going to be in the class, you should make them private. Which probably should be the case anyways. Generally you want full control of any instances of a database, which means making all calls to it within your control, and the best way to ensure this is to make it private. Allowing a user to possibly control its state is asking for trouble. If you need to open another database, which is the only reason I can think of for making it public, then you should simply create a new object for it. This will also make having these methods static quite unnecessary.

Why are you declaring `$dbh` static? Just make it a private variable and call it with `$this`. Maybe there is a reason for doing it this way, but I wouldn't know it. I tend to steer clear of the static keyword.

Final thoughts. Your variables should be easily identifiable. Yes, I understand what a `$dbh` is, but it should be clear for those who don't. I would simply call it something like `$handle` or if I might end up using multiple handles `$db_handle`. But `$dsn` and `$sth` (statement handle?) kind of have me stumped. Make them clear so that people reading your code at a later date will know what they mean. If you don't wish to change the variable names themselves, then at least use PHP Doc notes to describe what they are.